# How do I clean up my machine after unknowing mixing conda with pip?

Tags: anaconda

I've been using conda and pip interchangeably unknowing of the conflicts I've caused. How do I clean my machine (Linux Ubuntu 18.04) and start fresh so I'm uable to use conda exclusively?

Comment: Delete your environment and simply create a new one. Easy as that. For sure you know what a conda environment is, since you are not an amateur and you are reading the docs ...

Answer (score 0):

pip freeze > requirements.txt

pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y

conda install anaconda-clean

anaconda-clean

anaconda-clean --yes

gedit .bashrc

Delete the section that initalizes your anaconda environment and save then

close the file.